# A better way to generate and parse Bash output with Python?

Tags: python, bash, scripting, automation

#### CONTEXT

I have a few different scripts with the end goal of generating bash code with the following type of tagging system with any given command:

```
### <!-- BOF HTTPDERRORS --> ###
HTTPDERRORS=()
for OUTPUT in "$(sudo find /|grep error_log)"
do
  HTTPDERRORS+=("$OUTPUT")
done
# replace array results with tag
echo "$(echo "$HTTPDERRORS"|sed "s/$/ [HTTPDERRORS]/g")"
### <!-- EOF HTTPDERRORS --> ### >
```

------

```
/var/log/httpd/error_log-20150412 [HTTPDERRORS]
/var/log/httpd/error_log-20150405 [HTTPDERRORS]
/var/log/httpd/error_log [HTTPDERRORS]
```

Which allows it to be parsed with python code below:

```
if "[HTTPDERRORS]" in line:
    myhttpderrors = line.split('\n')
    for output in myhttpderrors:
        httpderrors.append(output)
```

and I use the script snippet below to add a command:

```
COMMAND=${OPTARG}

### <!-- BOF $TITLE_UPPER --> ### \n
$TITLE_UPPER=()
for OUTPUT in \"\$($COMMAND)\"
do
  "$TITLE_UPPER"+=(\"\$OUTPUT\")
done

echo \"\$(echo \"\$$TITLE_UPPER\"|sed \"s/\$/ [$TITLE_UPPER]/g\")\"

### <!-- EOF $TITLE_UPPER --> ### >

" > "$DIR/commands/$TITLE_LOWER.sh"
```

#### PROBLEM

This works fine for simple commands like "ls -lha" or "fdisk -l" where there isn't any logic involved, but not so much when adding something like a for loop ("-a" adds command, "-r" removes):

```
./manage_commands.sh -a -t "genchkcfg" -c "for i in $(chkconfig --list | grep 3:off | awk '{print $1}'); do echo -e "\n= $i ="; service $i status; done|grep running)"
```

```
GENCHKCFG=()
for OUTPUT in "$(for i in $(chkconfig --list | grep 3:off | awk '{print }');   do echo -e n=)"
do
  GENCHKCFG+=("$OUTPUT")
done

echo "$(echo "$GENCHKCFG"|sed "s/$/ [GENCHKCFG]/g")"

### <!-- EOF GENCHKCFG --> ###
```

Produces the following error:

```
bash commands/genchkcfg.sh
commands/genchkcfg.sh: command substitution: line 9: syntax error near   unexpected token `)'
commands/genchkcfg.sh: command substitution: line 9: `for i in $(chkconfig --list | grep 3:off | awk '{print }'); do echo -e $i)"'
```

#### GOAL

Is there a better, yet still elegant, way to do this that would ensure things like for loops and if statements as a one-liner are pretty much guaranteed to be added without error every time?

Comment: A good question, with a detailed accounting of attempts. I just want to take the time to thank you for trying, and for providing useful code examples. Not many do.

Comment: I do agree with @GamesBrainiac, It is great to have the code and some context, but on the other hand too much context will deter many readers - you should try to reduce your problem to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to make helpful comments and answers more likely.

Comment: Why do you want the BASH code? Are you writing to files that are then going to be run externally or are you simply looking to run the commands? I see that you are creating scripts but am wondering if, ultimately, it would be easier to make those call directly from Python (via subprocess, etc.)

Comment: Games Brainiac: Thanks. I like to make sure people know where I'm coming from when I ask a question. Michael Jaros: that's why I posted snippets instead of full code, and labeled sections so folks could skip around, but will consider it more for next time. @tom stratton: the bash code gets ran remotely as a sysinfo gathering script and passed back to the python script to be parsed locally, converting it to python would break existing convention and is not an option unfortunately.

Comment: Not sure if this is giving you trouble, but if you are applying a format to a string (print "something".format()) remember to double your `{`'s and `}`'s. Otherwise python will remove them from your string and the word within. So `{print }` should become `{{print }}` **only** if you are using formatting.

Comment: Are you sure that `\"\$($COMMAND)\"` works even for minimal statements? To be sure, I echoed that expression with `COMMAND=\":\"` and `COMMAND=:` and I got the same error: `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('`

Comment: @nivix zixer: cool, hasn't given me any trouble so far but will definitely refactor if needed, though the Python side only parses a text file that gets generated with the bash output not the actual code.  Thanks for the suggestion! MichaelJaros: Works fine: http://pastebin.com/ehccAZs7. Send a pastebin and I can take a look at what you're trying.